# Error al multiplicar dos números enteros en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
for a in 0 ..< numeroDias! {
    if a > 0 {
        let cont = a
        let interval = 60*60*24
        let fDesdeDos = fDesde.addingTimeInterval(interval * cont)
    }
}
```

Pero me aparece este error:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands

El error me aparece aquí: `(interval * cont)`

La variable `fdesde` => `var fDesde = calendar.startOfDay(for: "2016-12-7")`

Comment: ¿Podrías poner que contiene la variable `fDesde`? Sin embargo, fíjate que en la variable `cont` pones `:Int` después de la variable y no haces lo mismo para la variable `interval`.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta @Error404

Comment: Fíjate en lo que he añadido. No sé si tendrá algo que ver.

Comment: no tengo ni idea de swift pero igual esperaba otra "cosa" en un parámetro (entiendo que eso será una función ¿no?). ¿Y si haces la operacion antes? `let resul = (interval * cont)` y luego le pasas la variable en vez de multiplicar en la función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Swift 3.0, la [solución ofrecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32912/22231) por [Patrick](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16954/patrick) cambia un poco:

```
let numeroDias = 5
let hoy = Date()
let dias = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: numeroDias, to: hoy)
```

No obstante, con respecto a tu código:

`let fDesdeDos = fDesde.addingTimeInterval(interval * cont)`

`func addingTimeInterval(ti: TimeInterval)` espera un `TimeInterval` como argumento, que es un typealias de `Double`.

> public typealias TimeInterval = Double

No entiendo el por qué de ese mensaje de error, pero si quieres solucionarlo bastaría con hacer:

```
let fDesdeDos = fDesde.addingTimeInterval(Double(interval * cont))
```

Comment: Efectivamente se soluciono el problema añadiendo: (Double(interval * cont))